# How to get bounds with react-leaflet

Tags: reactjs, leaflet, react-leaflet

I want to get bounds of the current map so that I can search those bounds with the Overpass API.

For leaflet I know the method is just map.getBounds(), but I don't know how to implement that in react-leaflet.

```
class SimpleExample extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      lat: 51.505,
      lng: -0.09,
      zoom: 13,
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    console.log(this.refs.map.getBounds())
  }

  render() {
    const position = [this.state.lat, this.state.lng];
    return (
      <Map center={position} zoom={this.state.zoom} ref='map'>
        <TileLayer
          attribution='&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
          url='http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png'
        />
      </Map>
    );
  }
}
```

This is what I've tried.  Error says that `this.refs.map.getBounds` isn't a function.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try `this.refs.map.leafletElement.getBounds`.

According to the [documentation](https://react-leaflet.js.org/docs/en/components):

> You can directly access the Leaflet element created by a component
>   using this.leafletElement in this component. This leaflet element
>   is usually created in componentWillMount(), except for the Map
>   component where it can only be created after the  container is
>   rendered.

which is a round about way of saying they store the leaflet object as `leafletElement` property on their component objects.

Comment: i kind of don't get the part `except for the Map component where it can only be created after the container is rendered.` am i able to get new bounds for each render? thank you

Comment: Access it in `componentDidMount` and `componentDidUpdate`

Comment: You can also take a look to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51399480/react-leaflet-how-to-get-map-bounds-and-center-it if this answer doesn't fix the problem (for me, the `ref='map'` part was missing)

Comment: refs is deprecated

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled upon this earlier, the way I solved it is by using the **useMap hook** from react-leaflet like this:

```
import { useMap } from "react-leaflet";

function ShowBounds() {
const mMap = useMap();
let newBounds = mMap.getBounds();
console.log(newBounds);
}
```

Worked for me. Hope this helps.