# React-leaflet how to get map bounds and center it?

Tags: react-leaflet

I want to get this map bounds and center it 
[map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PXBpZ.jpg)

I tried with getBounds() and getCenter() but it was undefined.

then i found this but it says Cannot read property 'leafletElement' of undefined

Thanks for your help in forward.

```js
class FortMap extends Component {
  state = {
    lat: 51.505,
    lng: -0.09,
    zoom: 18,
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    console.log(this.refs.map.leafletElement.getBounds);
  }

  
  render() {
    const { lat , lng , zoom } = this.state;
    const position = [0, 0];

    return (
        <Map center={position} zoom={zoom}>
          <TileLayer
            url={fortniteMap}
            attribution="&copy; <a href=&quot;http://osm.org/copyright&quot;>OpenStreetMap</a> contributors"
          />
        </Map>
    )
  }
}

export default FortMap;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seems you forgot to assign `ref` attribute for a `Map` component:

```
<Map ref='map' center={position} zoom={zoom}>
  ...
</Map>
```

to get a reference to leaflet instance:

```
componentDidMount(){
    let mapInst =  this.refs.map.leafletElement;
}
```

[Demo](https://codepen.io/vgrem/pen/VBWoBO)

Comment: refs is deprecated