# react-leaflet with functional components and ImageOverlay

Tags: javascript, reactjs, leaflet, react-leaflet

This is my first time using Leaflet, so I've been a bit confused while trying to understand the docs. I am trying to create a custom map with react-leaflet by using the ImageOverlay component. I am struggling to get the Map component size to be the same size as my image. I'm afraid I don't quite understand `bounds`, but I think that's what I'm supposed to be using here. I tried using `getBounds()` to see if that can get the bounds I need, but I don't think my implementation with the `refs` is correct. Here is my code so far:

```
import React, { useState, useRef, useEffect } from "react";
import { Map, ImageOverlay } from "react-leaflet";
import { CRS, getBounds } from "leaflet";

export default () => {
    const [bounds, setBounds] = useState([]);
    const mapRef = useRef(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        setBounds(mapRef.current.leafElement.getBounds());
    }, []);

    return (
        <Map
            center={initialPos}
            zoom={0}
            ref={mapRef}
            minZoom={0}
            crs={CRS.Simple}
        >
            <ImageOverlay url="https://i.imgur.com/Ion6X7C.jpg" />
        </Map>
    );
};
```

Logging the new `bounds` in the `useEffect`, I get an object that looks like this:

```
LatLngBounds {
  _southWest: LatLng {lat: -110, lng: -95},
  _northEast: LatLng {lat: 290, lng: 565}
}
```

But I still get the following error:

```
Cannot read property 'lat' of undefined
```

I have referenced [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40728638/how-to-get-bounds-with-react-leaflet/40728869) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50861984/how-do-you-call-fitbounds-when-using-leaflet-react) to help me figure out how to set the bounds in a way that will fit the Map to the size of my image, but have been struggling on converting them to functional components

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for the map instance which can be taken from `mapRef.current.leafletElement` instead of `mapRef.current`.

You can achieve that in a more simple way without passing bounds several times as props. Also you cannot extract the map bounds before the component is mounted because simply it has not been initialised therefore it has no `center` and `zoom` by the time you are trying to get its bounds. You will receive a relevant error if you tried to get it:

> Error
>       Set map center and zoom first.

So you need to create the `imageOverlay` instance like this using functional component:

```
const mapRef = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const map = mapRef.current.leafletElement;
    const bounds = [[-26.5, -25], [1021.5, 1023]];
    const image = L.imageOverlay("https://i.imgur.com/Ion6X7C.jpg", bounds).addTo(
      map
    );
    // this is what you were looking for
    map.fitBounds(image.getBounds());
  }, []);
```

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-leaflet-with-functional-components-and-imageoverlay-u225j)

Comment: another working example, i think i'm getting familiar with your flow of accessing the element directly and not relying much on React-leaflet components